# Red Gate .NET Reflector: How to install and use "Assembly Visualizer" Add-in?

Tags: dll

I just went to this page: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/add-ins

I downloaded "Assembly Visualizer" and unzipped the file.

What are the next steps in order to use this add-in in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the red-gate forums for installing add-ins in visual studio.

*Before version 7.6 of .NET Reflector, the desktop application was downloaded as a zip file and the extension was then integrated into VS through the desktop app's Tools>Integration menu item.
For newer versions of .NET Reflector, you can install both the .NET Reflector desktop application and VS extension via the single installer. The extension is also available from the Visual Studio Gallery.
Please note: If you have Visual Studio 2005 or 2008, you will need the Sunset Build of the extension, available from here.*

Here is your link for that post -> [Link](http://forums.reflector.net/questions/777/how-do-i-install-the-visual-studio-add-in.html)